# TCP socket read/write freezes server

Tags: c, tcp

I want to implement protocol using TCP sockets in C which works kind of this way:

1. Client connects to server and sends filename that it wants to
   download
2. Server reads that value and checks whether it is valid filename (does it exist on the server) + sends `ACCEPT` or `FAILURE` status to client
3. Client reads that status and prepares itself to download + sends `READY` status to server
4. Server sends file and closes connection

**Server code**:

```
char response[128];
int bytes_read;
while ((bytes_read = read(info.socket, response, 128)) > 0) {}

if (valid_request(files, files_count, response)) {
    write(info.socket, MC_ACCEPT, 4);
} else {
    write(info.socket, MC_FAILURE, 4);
}
```

**Client code**:

```
int w_status = write(sck, requested_file, strlen(requested_file));
if (w_status < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error writing to socket. Status: %d", w_status);
    exit(1);
}

char status[4];
while ((resp = read(sck, status, 4)) > 0) {}

if (strcmp(status, MC_ACCEPT) == 0) {
    printf("ACCEPTED!\n");
} else if (strcmp(status, MC_ACCEPT) == 0) {
    printf("FAILURE\n");
} else {
    printf("DONT KNOW\n");
}

close(sck);
```

The problem is that server freezes itself on the `read()` part. It looks like client sends the filename and waits for server response (with status) but server is frozen at `read()`.

Am I somehow blocking the TCP socket? What is wrong with my reasoning?

Comment: @Barmar my mistake, I didn't have it in my real code

Comment: Have you tried doing a packet capture to see if the message is being sent to the server?

Comment: @Barmar what is interesting when I first run a server, then client and it hangs, but after that I kill client process with CTRL + C the server seems to get the message just right, but not until client process is alive

Comment: Your server code does nothing but wait for requests. Have you considered sending the file that was asked for?

Comment: @EJP this code I posted here is not complete. I am sending file later

Comment: So your question is utterly pointless. You need to send the file immediately after the MC_ACCEPT, not 'later'. There is no later. You're stuck in this loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the server side:

```
char response[128];
int bytes_read;
while ((bytes_read = read(info.socket, response, 128)) > 0) {}
```

You try to read those 128 chars in several `read` calls. But it will block forever until client closes the socket (it's TCP connected, there's always something to read unless peer closes connection).

And if the data arrives in more than 1 chunk, your code is incorrect, because the first chunk will be overwritten by the next one, and so on. You have to change the offset of your buffer, and do not attempt to read 128 bytes every time, or you'll get stuck.

```
int bytes_read = 0;
while (bytes_read < 128)
{
  int currently_read = read(info.socket, response + currently_read, 128-bytes_read);
  bytes_read += currently_read;
}
```

On the client side, same kind of issues too:

You seem to wait for 4 chars.

You try to read those 4 chars in the first `read`. But you don't check if 4 chars are actually read (return code discarded).

After that, you read using a loop until you get 0 bytes. But since connection doesn't end, you're stuck there.

What you want is to read exactly 4 bytes before doing something else.

And increase your buffer size & null-terminate your string or `strcmp` will fail.

```
char status[5];
status[4] = '\0';
int nb_read = 0;
while (nb_read < 4)
{
  int currently_read = read(sck, status + nb_read, 4-nb_read);
  nb_read += currently_read;
}
```

Comment: Your explanation was a key to understand my problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're not processing the request inside the `while` loop:

```
while ((bytes_read = read(info.socket, response, 128)) > 0) {}
```

This keeps looping until `read()` returns `0`, which happens when the client closes the connection, or gets an error and returns `-1`. After it reads the request from the client, it goes back and calls `read()` again. Since the client hasn't sent anything else, this blocks.

This is why killing the client gets it unstuck. That closes the connection, so it gets EOF and `read()` returns `0`.

You need to process the input inside the loop:

```
while ((bytes_read = read(info.socket, response, sizeof response -1)) > 0) {
    response[bytes_read] = '\0'; // add string null terminator
    if (valid_request(files, files_count, response)) {
        write(info.socket, MC_ACCEPT, 4);
    } else {
        write(info.socket, MC_FAILURE, 4);
    }
}
```

Comment: but cannot `read(info.socket, response, sizeof response -1)` return less than `sizeof response -1` ?

Comment: Yes, it can. He actually needs to design the protocol so that there's some way for the server to tell where the request ends, either with a length prefix or a delimiter character, then keep reading until he gets the whole message. Without this, the best he can do is hope that `read()` will return the whole message, which is reasonably likely.